Find appropriate bound of an integral
Let $t \in (t_0, + \infty)$ for $t_0$ an arbitrarily large fixed constant, $\alpha \in (0,1)$ a number close to 1 and $s \in [3t/4,t]$. I'm wondering if it's possible to prove the following bound
$$\int_{s - s^{\alpha}}^{t - t^\alpha} \frac{1}{u^{1/2} \log(u) (t - u)}du \le C(\alpha, t_0)   \frac{(t - s)^\gamma}{t^{1/2 + \gamma}}\quad ? $$
Where $\gamma \in (0,1)$ and $C(\alpha, t_0) \ll 1$ by adjusting $\alpha, t_0$ (which are free parameters in my problem).
My attempts
One can prove that
\begin{align}
\int_{s - s^{\alpha}}^{t - t^\alpha} \frac{1}{u^{1/2} \log(u) (t - u)}du & \le \frac{1}{(s - s^\alpha)^{1/2}\log(s - s^\alpha)}\int_{t/2}^{t - t^\alpha} \frac{1}{(t - u)}du \\
&\le C \frac{1}{t^{1/2}\log(t)}\int_{t/2}^{t - t^\alpha} \frac{1}{(t - u)}du \\
&\le C \frac{1}{t^{1/2}\log(t)}(1 - \alpha)\log(t),\\
&\le C \frac{(1 - \alpha)t^\gamma}{t^{1/2 + \gamma}}.
\end{align}
Here $C(\alpha, t_0) = C(1 - \alpha)$ can be made as small as needed by taking $\alpha$ close to $1$. This is close to the inequality I want, but I need $(t - s)^\gamma$ at the top, not $t^\gamma$. By similar techniques,
I manage to prove that
\begin{align}
\int_{s - s^{\alpha}}^{t - t^\alpha} \frac{1}{u^{1/2} \log(u) (t - u)}du  
&\le \frac{C}{\log(t_0)} \frac{(t - s)^\gamma}{t^{1/2 + \gamma - \varepsilon}},
\end{align}
with $C(t_0, \alpha) = C/\log t_0$ small for $t_0$ large, and $\varepsilon = 1 - \alpha \in (0,1)$ is arbitrarily small for $\alpha$ approaching 1. Again, this is close but not quite what I want as I'm losing $t^\varepsilon$ decay in time.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
